# Bootstrap columns are breaking to new line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I fall into a trouble with bootsrap columns - **on medium display size** they breaks to new line, I can't figure out why.

Here is the image of that break.
[image]

I see that on 4th div `clear: left` is applied, but why? As I understand it should be on next div.

`<div class="visible-xs clearfix"></div>` is for [column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

[Here is the site](http://darlingdove.ru), where you can look at this bug by yourself, just scroll down to products after banner in the middle of the page.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi @C1one_38, is the product gallery a plugin? if so, maybe you can give a try to the developer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda, no, its just plain php rendering

Comment: does it always happend after the banner ? Did you try it removing the banner ?

Comment: How about removing your div clearfix?

Comment: @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda, I only implement this logic on lower products list (added `div.visible-xs.clearfix`). Tried to remove banner, the bug still there

Comment: @claudios I can't, I need it to implement column resets, as said

Comment: Can you try what @claudios is sugesting ?

Comment: ok, what if you set 5 columns all the time ? or 4 ? would be ok for you ?

Comment: The .visible-xs.clearfix is only available for XS screen, not for medium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like bootstrap doesn't provide any way to solve this issue.

Had to do it by myself by removing bootstrap column resets (`div.visible-xs.clearfix`) and make them manually, as claudios suggested in comments:

```
@media (max-width: 970px) {
    .product-layout:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```